# Why python 2.7 request fails for ssl when openssl s_client -connect works?

Tags: python, ssl

I am trying to can a server which is signed with a self-signed certificate. I have

```
openssl s_client -connect myserveraddress:myport
```

working

```
---
SSL handshake has read 4620 bytes and written 466 bytes
---
```

but when I run my python code:

```
import requests

url = MyURL

querystring = {"q":"admin"}

headers = {
'content-type': "application/json",
'authorization': "Bearer SOME-TOKEN",
'cache-control': "no-cache"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring, verify=False)
```

it fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 502, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 612, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)
```

I installed all the packages from other SO questions with no success.
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: In most cases both s_client and requests will succeed. The cases where they differ depend on a particular server configuration which result in no cipher overlap or no protocol version overlap or similar. It is also possible that different version of the OpenSSL library are used for s_client and python and cause this problem etc. This means that the help can not be provided without knowing all the details which might cause the problems. And there can be bugs related to a specific version of requests or python. Please have a look at similar question to get a feeling for all the details needed.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by upgrade to python 2.7.13 from 2.7.10 and install of open SSL packages and adding the self-signed certificate to the store